# Getting message chat id Telegram

Tags: php, codeigniter

### Problem

Hi I want to get message chat id in telegram by Codeigniter. I am not so good in programming. I think I am not using array script properly.

### That gives me error

Cannot use object of type stdClass as array **C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\admin\application\controllers\lifeChange.php on line 20**

## PHP ##

```
$chat_id = $update['result'][0]['message']['chat']['id'];
```

### Array

```
stdClass Object
(
[ok] => 1
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [update_id] => 188680055
                [message] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [message_id] => 9
                        [from] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => [number id]
                                [first_name] => $ravshan
                                [last_name] => = array(' ');
                                [username] => antiSmoke
                            )

                        [chat] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => [number id]
                                [first_name] => $ravshan
                                [last_name] => = array(' ');
                                [username] => antiSmoke
                                [type] => private
                            )

                        [date] => 1469289772
                        [text] => /start
                        [entities] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [type] => bot_command
                                        [offset] => 0
                                        [length] => 6
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

)

Comment: Can you post the contents of the $update variable?

Comment: Yes I know I should use that method but howto use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the contents of the `$update` variable you posted, here is how you can find the correct syntax, step-by-step:

You wrote:

```
$chat_id = $update['result'][0]['message']['chat']['id'];
```

However, $update is an object (this is the first line `stdClass Object`), so to access `result` you must use:

```
$chat_id = $update->result;
```

`result` is an array, so you can indeed access it by index:

```
$chat_id = $update->result[0];
```

`result[0]` is an object:

```
$chat_id = $update->result[0]->message;
```

`message` is an object:

```
$chat_id = $update->result[0]->message->chat;
```

`chat` is an object. Here is the line of code you need:

```
$chat_id = $update->result[0]->message->chat->id;
```

One you are used to manipulating arrays and objects, you will be able to write this kind of code very quickly. You just need to know the internal structure of the variable you want to access, and `var_dump` help a lot with that.

Documentation:

- [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)
- [Classes and Objects > properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php)

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Where? What are you doing? What does `var_dump($update->result[0]->message->chat->id)` displays?

Comment: I debugged with var_dump that gives me Null